# Validate FQDN in C# using regex

Tags: c#, regex, fqdn

I wrote the following pattern in C# to validate a FQDN received from a user:

```
(`?=^.{1,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d+\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,})$)
```

I want to allow the user to enter the following FQDN:

```
<name>.<letter><digit>
```

such as "aa.a1". For "aa.a1" my regex detects the FQDN as invalid, and for "aa.1a" it detects it as valid. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a RegEx, you can load the string into a [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) and use the different methods and properties to figure out if it is a FQDN.

```
Uri uri = new Undri(myFQDN);
string host = uri.Host;
bool isAbsolute = uri.IsAbsoluteUri;
```

Comment: You'll need to wrap that in a try/catch block to trap for UriFormatException's

Comment: @RRR - Why is that? Simply stating it's not good without explaining why is hardly going to help with finding _suitable_ solutions.

Comment: because when I uses in this way, for this code: " Uri uri = new Uri("aa.aa"); string host = uri.Host; bool isAbsolute = uri.IsAbsoluteUri;" I accept this exception "The format of the URI could not be determined.", furthermore , I have a spacial rules for the FQDN, can I suit the Uri object to my requirements?

Comment: @RRR - You can always inherit from the `Uri` class and create a customized version.

Comment: anyway, I prefer to use on regex.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to even try to decode that huge regex, use the [Uri.IsWellFormedUriString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx) method instead.  That already does what you are looking for.